# Python telegram bot - How to wait for a job to finish then stop the updater?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a bot that gets images from a website and sends them to a channel, and I want it to run that job once when executed, then stop the updater, effectively closing the terminal it's being executed on.

I am using sleep to wait for the job to finish at the moment, but I was wondering if there's a better solution for my problem. Here's how it looks now:

```
from telegram.ext import Defaults, Updater
from telegram import ParseMode
from time import sleep

def my_job(context: CallbackContext):
    # other stuff
    pic = open("pic.png", "rb")
    context.bot.send_photo(
            chat_id=CHAT_ID,
            photo=pic,
            caption="caption",
        )

def main():
    defaults = Defaults(parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, defaults=defaults, workers=32)  # type: ignore
    
    j = updater.job_queue
    j.run_once(my_job, when=0)

    updater.start_polling(poll_interval=1.0, timeout=5.0)
    sleep(15)
    updater.stop()
```

Comment: Hi @vnsrz: can you add more details as to where exactly the problem is, and what is the expected output? Questions that have a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) usually get quicker answers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify: You want the script to fetch an image from a website, send it to a channel and then exit, without listening to updates from users. Did I get that correctly?